# how to build a voto-questions database in django?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, user-profile, vote

i want keep track of which question and answer the user has voted(up and down),so this is how i did it ,its not working

this is my question class

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    questionbody = models.TextField()
    questioncontent = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('question post date')
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    downvote = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    view = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

and this is my userprofile class(extends user)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag) 
    # favorite_question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    # upvote_question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    # downvote_question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    # upvote_answer = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    # downvote_answer = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    integration = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    level = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

if uncomment the line
run the synvdb command it will show the error

```
 access for m2m field 'favorite-question' clashes with related m2m field 'question-userprofile_set',add a related_name argument to thr definition for 'favorite-question'
```

and same error shows up for the rest 4 line. am really new to django ,please help

Answer (score 0):

About the error, you have to defined the related name if you want to use a relationship of same type across models:

for example:

```
favorite_question = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name='favourite_question')
```

Comment: i get it working,thanx anyway,but do you think there is a better way to do this, i mean upvote and downvote, kind of duplicate,can't i just have one vote, and tell the difference somehow？